# order of multiple select statements joined by union

Tags: sql-server

I have a bunch of select statements that I've joined together with Union.  The order of the output seems to be defaulting to least to greatest.  I'd prefer to have the output in the same order of the select statements.

Is there a simple fix to assign an "order id" to each select statement that would keep the output in the same order?

```
select sum(amount) from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV where [Account #] like 4010 or [Account #] like 4020
union
select sum(amount) from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV where [Account #] like 4025 or [Account #] like 4030 or [Account #] like 4040
union
select sum(amount) from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV where [Account #] like 4045
```

Comment: Since you have no order by on your query you cannot ensure the order.

Comment: So are you saying that including an "order by" statement prior to my code will keep the output in the same order as the statements?

Comment: Well....yes. If you want order in your results you MUST supply an order by. But in your case you need to get a little more creative.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comments you need to get a little bit creative to ensure that the rows are in a certain order. This will keep the results from each of your queries in the same order.

```
select sum(amount), SortOrder = 1 from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV where [Account #] like 4010 or [Account #] like 4020
union
select sum(amount), 2 from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV where [Account #] like 4025 or [Account #] like 4030 or [Account #] like 4040
union
select sum(amount), 3 from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV where [Account #] like 4045
order by SortOrder
```

I suspect you could make this a little simpler and do something like this.

```
select sum(amount)
from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV
where [Account #] in (4010, 4020, 4025, 4030, 4040, 4045)
group by [Account #]
order by 
    case [Account #]
        when 4010 then 1
        when 4020 then 1
        when 4025 then 2
        when 4030 then 2
        when 4040 then 2
        when 4045 then 3
    end
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try working with this and see how far i get.

Comment: Wouldn't this return 6 lines in the answer vs 3 lines?

Comment: @KeithL actually it could return more. And in the original question there is no way to know how many rows would be returned. It just had some where clauses.

Comment: There's no group by. It would return 1 summary number for each UNION

Comment: Edited to add a where clause to the aggregate query.

Comment: @KeithL good point....as I said the aggregate is a shot in the dark because there is no data. Look at the first query, it has the same queries as the OP but with a sort.

Comment: @SeanLange I like your answer and I am going to throw a curve ball below.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider a linking table if the groups get extremely large.

For example:

```
AcctNum  GroupName
4010     G1
4020     G1
4025     G2
...
```

Then join this is and group it

```
select GroupName,sum(amount) from friday.dbo.FMDR_Friday_CSV c
join LinkingTable lt on c.[Account #] = lt.AcctNum 
group by GroupName
```